# SharePoint REST Api filter on date

Tags: rest, api, datetime, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I am trying to filter out items by date. I want to get one item that has the dateFrom equel or bigger to today and dateTo equel or less then today. This is my query and reformat date function. In SharePoint Online I have the date set to `only date`. by default sharePoint sets the time part to 23:00:00. Thats why the static use of it. The `´ge dateFrom´` part of the query works fine but the `le dateTo` ignores the equel part. So if dateTo is set to `2018-03-19`. I dont get any items 
 returned with the dateTo set to that date `2018-03-19`. Is my query wrong?

```
     var requestUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + _weaklyQuestion + "')/items?$select=Id,Title,answersOptions,dateFrom,dateTo&$filter=('" + ReFormatTime() + "' ge dateFrom) and ('" + ReFormatTime() + "' le dateTo)&$top=1";

        function ReFormatTime() {
        var date = new Date(),
            year = date.getFullYear(),
            month = date.getMonth() + 1,
            dt = date.getDate();

        if (dt < 10) {
            dt = '0' + dt;
        }
        if (month < 10) {
            month = '0' + month;
        }
        return year + '-' + month + '-' + dt + 'T23:00:00Z';
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to wrap your formatted time string inside a `datetime()`

```
var requestUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + _weaklyQuestion + "')/items?$select=Id,Title,answersOptions,dateFrom,dateTo&$filter=(datetime('" + ReFormatTime() + "') ge dateFrom) and (datetime('" + ReFormatTime() + "') le dateTo)&$top=1";
```

Comment: Sorry for the late replay. I solved it a bit differently then your suggestion. But you put me on the right track. I’ll post the solution on Monday.

Answer (score 5):

For SharePoint Online version - Date Range Comparison:

1) Convert dates to be use for comparison in *2019-04-18T23:59:00.000Z* format.

2) Add **000Z** at the end of the date and form rest query like below.

```
/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('ListName')/items?$orderby=Created desC&$filter=(Created ge datetime'2019-04-17T00:00:00.000Z') and (Created le datetime'2019-04-18T23:59:00.000Z')
```

Comment: This worked for me.  The checked answer mentions having parenthesis just after datetime : datetime('<iso-date-value>')   That did not work for me.